# How to interact with a map provider in Adobe Animate CC?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, animate-cc

I'm using Animate CC for a few month, I need to use online or offline interactive maps in some projects based on AIR platform, Is there any map service for Animate CC?

Comment: Google > as3 google maps

Comment: I tried before, all things i could find was old methods or component.

Comment: The first link I get is 2-years-old thread which links to google code project (https://code.google.com/archive/p/gmaps-api-as3/) fully (as its text states) compliant with Flash CS6, which is 1 version back from Animate CC, so you should have no problems with it.